# loading data into UITextField isn't working

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

no idea why, but this simply isn't working. it's supposed to load some values from a plist file, and load them into some UITextFields. it does output with the NSLogs everything you would expect, but but the text on the UITextFields aren't the same. it almost seems as if its randomly choosing where to put what.

```
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist",file]];

    NSDictionary *loadDict;

    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]){
        NSLog(@"hey its there!");
        loadDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

        [numSidesBox setText:[loadDict valueForKey:@"numSides"]];
        NSLog([loadDict valueForKey:@"numSides"]);
        [numSidesBox setText:[loadDict valueForKey:@"numDice"]];
        NSLog([loadDict valueForKey:@"numDice"]);
        [numSidesBox setText:[loadDict valueForKey:@"modifier"]];
        NSLog([loadDict valueForKey:@"modifier"]);
        [numSidesBox setText:[loadDict valueForKey:@"numRolls"]];
        NSLog([loadDict valueForKey:@"numRolls"]);
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"hey its not =(");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are setting the text of the same text box again and again.  So, `numSidesBox` should always contain the text of `[loadDict valueForKey:@"numRolls"]`.  I assume that you have more than one text field, so just change `numSidesBox` to the other variables like `numDiceBox` or whatever you call them.

P.S. I would also suggest using `objectForKey:` rather than `valueForKey:`.

Comment: yea sorry thats a copy/paste error on my memory's part, and thanks for the objectForKey tip. i'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 1):

You said "TextFields" plural, but you are only using one UITextField(?).

```
[numSidesBox setText:[loadDict valueForKey:@"numSides"]];
NSLog([loadDict valueForKey:@"numSides"]);
[numSidesBox setText:[loadDict valueForKey:@"numDice"]];
NSLog([loadDict valueForKey:@"numDice"]);
[numSidesBox setText:[loadDict valueForKey:@"modifier"]];
NSLog([loadDict valueForKey:@"modifier"]);
[numSidesBox setText:[loadDict valueForKey:@"numRolls"]];
NSLog([loadDict valueForKey:@"numRolls"]);
```

Only numSidesBox? Is it correct?

Comment: oh jeez how terribly embarrassing. seems copy/paste comes with a bit of memory obligation ;) i'm sorry for wasting your time. thank you!

Comment: No problem mate. Dont forge't to accept an answer (accept Alex and vote me up) He answered first.